# Strange PDO MySQL Problem

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to perform a query in a PHP script.  The query works fine in my MySQL client however it does not seem to working within my code.  I am using PDO.  I am thinking it might have limitations, because it seems to work fine with a less complicated query.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT D.status, D.createdBy, D.createDate, D.modifiedBy, D.modifiedDate,D.IPAddress,  D.adminStatus, D.campus, D.buildingID, D.deviceShortName, D.distributionID, D.networkKey, D.deviceName, D.test, D.pkDevices, D.DNSRule, D.Domain, D.DNSOverride, D.noDNS, D.pkModel, DM.Model, DM.pkManufacturer, M.manufacturer FROM Devices AS D INNER JOIN DeviceModel AS DM ON D.pkModel = DM.pkModel INNER JOIN Manufacturer AS M ON DM.pkManufacturer =  M.pkManufacturer WHERE D.status = '1' AND D.adminStatus = 'Active' ORDER BY D.deviceName
```

Here is where I am trying to call it in my script:

```
$dbhDevices = newPDO('mysql:host='.$_SESSION['OpsDBServer'].'.ops.tns.its.psu.edu;dbname='.$_SESSION['OpsDB'], $_SESSION['yoM'], $_SESSION['aMa']);
$sqlDevices = "SELECT D.status, D.createdBy, D.createDate, D.modifiedBy,
D.modifiedDate, D.IPAddress, D.adminStatus, D.campus, D.buildingID,
D.deviceShortName, D.distributionID, D.networkKey, D.deviceName, D.test,
D.pkDevices, D.DNSRule, D.Domain, D.DNSOverride, D.noDNS, D.pkModel, DM.Model,
DM.pkManufacturer, M.manufacturer
FROM Devices AS D
INNER JOIN DeviceModel AS DM ON D.pkModel = DM.pkModel
INNER JOIN Manufacturer AS M ON DM.pkManufacturer = M.pkManufacturer
WHERE D.status = '1' AND D.adminStatus = 'Active' ORDER BY D.deviceName";
foreach ($dbhDevices->query($sqlDevices) as $rowDevices)
{
```

Again, the query does work with the MySQL client.

Comment: What happens within the script? Are any errors generated or output? (You'll make it easier for people to help if you provide a bit more information.)

Comment: -1: "does not work" is never an adequate problem description.

Comment: just asking the obvious question,  is the newPDO a typo in your question? it should be new PDO() to instantiate the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by using a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN.  Strange, but it is working.

Answer (score 2):

try enabling errors if haven't done already:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$dbhDevices->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the older versions of PDO usage you have to "initialize" your PDO variable when you declare it for some reason. Try putting a line before this code that generically initializes `$dbhDevices` and see if that does the trick. I have my doubts because you say it works fine with less complicated queries but it's worth a try.